# beat: Connection error: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

I am deploying my Django backend on Heroku and I have used celery and Redis as a broker.
But I am getting these errors on the worker log:

```
2021-08-23T17:43:05.148602+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2021-08-23 17:43:05,148: ERROR/Beat] beat: Connection error: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer'). Trying again in 32.0 seconds...
2021-08-23T17:43:35.862615+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2021-08-23 17:43:35,862: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://:**@ec2-52-22-18-101.compute-1.amazonaws.com:30320//: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer').
2021-08-23T17:43:35.862624+00:00 app[worker.1]: Trying again in 32.00 seconds... (16/100)
```

setting.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://:*******.compute-1.amazonaws.com:port'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://:***********.compute-1.amazonaws.com:port'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SELERLIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = None
```

celery.py :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from datetime import timezone
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from celery.schedules import crontab, schedule

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'NewsApi.settings')
app = Celery('NewsApi')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-1-hour': {
        'task': 'Api.tasks.task_news_update',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='*/1'),
    }
}

app.conf.update(timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata')
# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Did you for instance try to connect to the redis backend manually?

Comment: @MarkM Yes, its working fine with the local URL `redis://localhost:6379`

Comment: Yes but if you need to access it from Heroku that's a different thing. Try to access the public redis endpoint. I'm guessing you haven't configured the network settings for Redis to be exposed to the internet. Not that I would recommend this, Redis' security is (last I checked) not designed to be exposed to the internet. It's better to run Celery on the same local/virtual network as Redis.

Comment: @MarkM Could you please share with me some resources on how to configure those settings or provide me the details that what I need to add in my settings?

Comment: I don't know AWS very well, they have a lot of [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/) though. But like I said, [exposing Redis to the internet is not recommended](https://redis.io/topics/security). So either move Redis into Heroku (I don't know if that's possible) or Celery into AWS.

Comment: I have the same connection error message when using Heroku to provide me with the redis credentials and running redis and celery within Heroku.